# Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\cosh^2(u)}{2x}}\,e^{-\frac{u^2}{2 t}}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi\,u}{2t }\right)\,\cosh(u)\,du$ is positive

Tags: definite-integrals, periodic-functions

I have been several days trying to prove that the following integral

$$I_t(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\cosh^2(u)}{2x}}\,e^{-\frac{u^2}{2 t}}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi\,u}{2t }\right)\,\cosh(u)\,du,\hspace{0.5cm}x,t>0$$

is positive ( $I_t(x)>0$ for all $x,t>0$) but I can't do it. Always, the way I choose is splitting the integrand in periodic regions and try to see that positive areas are bigger than negative areas. But, at least for me, this way not work. And believe me that I have tried a lot different variants !!!

So, maybe I should try to consider the function as such (not as a
sum of areas) and look for something with the derivatives with respect to x or even
with respect to t.

I also tried to prove that $I_t ^ 2 (x)>0$ trying to
apply something in the resulting double integral but I think is not a good idea.

It can also be used that
$$f (x) = \frac {e ^ {\frac {\pi ^ 2} {8t}}} {2 \pi \sqrt {tx ^ 3}} \, I_t(x) $$is a density function and thus $\int _ {- \infty} ^ {\infty} f (x) dx = 1$.

Please lend a hand. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to prove the integral is greater than $0$, I'll sketch a mode of proof. Consider the functions that comprise the integrand. $e^x$ is never less than $0$ in the real plane. $\cosh(x)$ is never less than $0$ in the real plane. $\cos(x)$ is your only real problem. Here's the thing to note, $cosh(x)$ increases slower than $e^{-cosh(x)^2}$ decreases. Since the function starts at 1 and ends up at $0$ on both sides of the interval, and since the integral of $/cos(x)$ is periodic and spends equal amounts of time + and -, the integral must be positive as the function decreases from 1 to 0 and spends equal amounts of time + and - after a certain point in the interval, which results in a integral of 0. Since only the beginning contributes more to the integral, and because its positive, the integral must be positive.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I don't know how to use the fundamental theorem of Calculus in this case. I don't wanna the real value of integral, I only wanna see that is positive.

Comment: @popi I sketched a proof

Comment: But the problem is that the first positive branch $[0,t]$ of $\cos(.)$ length $t$ while the second negative branch $[t,3t]$ of $\cos(.)$ length $2t$ and then you can't assure what you are saying. 
What do you think about?

Comment: I think that since the function starts at 1. The value is positive. Even if the period approaches 0, I think It can be argued the first period will be greater than all the rest. And by the evenly distributed periodicity of $\cos(x)$, F(x) stays positive. Hope that helps.