# Different way to show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\cosh^2(u)}{2x}}\,e^{-\frac{u^2}{2 t}}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi\,u}{2t }\right)\,\cosh(u)\,du > 0$

Tags: definite-integrals, periodic-functions

I have been long time trying to prove that the following integral

$$I_t(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\cosh^2(u)}{2x}}\,e^{-\frac{u^2}{2 t}}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi\,u}{2t }\right)\,\cosh(u)\,du,\hspace{0.5cm}x,t>0$$
is positive , that is, $I_t(x)>0\,\,\forall x,t>0$ but I haven't had success.

Basically, I have used the following way:  splitting the interval in differents regions where the integrand changes it sign and try to see that positive areas are bigger than negative areas. Unfortunately, this way not work (with a lot of different variants).

**Now, at this moment, I wonder by another different way to prove it.**

**Anybody knows how to prove that  this kind of function are positive in a different way? I only need the way, not the proof.**

Attach the graphic of $I_t(x)$ for $t=1$ (is very similar for others values of $t$)

[image]

and add, if interesting, that

$$f (x) = \frac {e ^ {\frac {\pi ^ 2} {8t}}} {2 \pi \sqrt {tx ^ 3}} \, I_t(x)$$

is a density function : $\displaystyle \int _ {- \infty} ^ {\infty} f (x) dx = 1$

Any help is welcome.

Comment: just as a note, the integrand is an even function of $u$.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But at the moment, hasn't been useful.

Comment: It's also a cosine transform, and I thought the function being transformed might be convex but it doesn't seem to be sadly.

Comment: Maybe it's evaluable by some properties of the fourier transform so?

Comment: But the transform variable, suppose $\displaystyle T=\frac{1}{t}$, also appears in the rest of integrand. Is this possible to be a cosine transform?

Comment: And also, because interval symmetry, we could change $\cos(u T)$ by $e^{i\,u T}$ and would talk about Fourier transform. But transform variable $T$ also appears in the rest of integrand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37783/discussion-between-ppooppii-and-snulty).

Comment: Let me notice that, since the integrand is even, it is enough to integrate it on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @AlexM. first comment$\ldots$

Comment: Seems like 3 of the 4 terms are always non-negative, so the issue is to compare the regions with positive and negative values of the cosine term.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\cosh^2(u)}{2x}}\,e^{-\frac{u^2}{2 t}}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi\,u}{2t }\right)\,\cosh(u)\,du$ is positive](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225394/prove-that-int-infty-inftye-frac-cosh2u2x-e-fracu22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integral $I_t(x)$ can also be written as:

\begin{equation}
I_t(x)=-e^{t/2}\,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\cosh^2(u+t)}{2x}}\,e^{-\frac{u^2}{2 t}}\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi\,u}{2t }\right)\,du
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tilde{I}_t(x)=e^{-1/2x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2x}}\,e^{-\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}^2(u)}{2 t}}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi\operatorname{arcsinh}(u)}{2t}\right)\,du
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_t(x)=e^{-\pi^2/8t}e^{-1/2x}\,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2x}}\,e^{-\frac{\operatorname{arccosh}^2(i u)}{2 t}}\,du
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_t(x)=i\,e^{-\pi^2/8t}\,\int_{-\infty+i\,\pi/2}^{\infty+i\,\pi/2}e^{\frac{\sinh^2(u)}{2x}}\,e^{-\frac{u^2}{2 t}}\,\sinh\left(u\right)\,du
\end{equation}

**In first three cases, I wonder if the integrand would be inferiorly  bounded by a odd function, the proof is finished.**

**It's possible?**

Comment: As another possible idea, since we're trying to show the integral is strictly positive, then suppose the opposite, $\exists x,t$ so that the integral is $\leq 0$. In both cases there should exist a value of $\exists x,t$ so that the integral is zero. Then calling the integrand $g(u,t,x)$, and fixing this $t,x$,this means for every $a\in [0,\infty)$, $$\int_0^a g(u,t,x)=- \int_a^\infty g(u,t,x).$$ So maybe now that you've a new parameter $a$, you can choose it large enough and make estimates on $g$ so that the two integrals can't equal in magnitude?

Comment: Since this isn't exactly an answer to your question, if I were you I would include this post in the question as an edit and then delete it.

Comment: Another transformation
$$I_t(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}}e^{-\pi^2/8t}e^{-1/4x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2t u^2}\text{cosh}(\pi  u) \,K_{1/2+i u}\left(\frac{1}{4x}\right)du$$
where $K_v(z)$ is the Modified Bessel function of second kind.